# XMLStarlet namespace issue/can't extract node value from XML

Tags: xml, batch-processing, xmlstarlet

I'm trying to assign a tag value from an XML file to a variable using a batch file and xmlstarlet (version 1.6.1). The XML file has a namespace and by defining the namespace in the xmlstarlet command I receive two errors.

The XML file (myApp-app.xml) looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/17.0">
    <!-- A string value of the format <0-999>.<0-999>.<0-999> that represents application version which can be used to check for application upgrade. 
    Values can also be 1-part or 2-part. It is not necessary to have a 3-part value.
    An updated version of application must have a versionNumber value higher than the previous version. Required for namespace >= 2.5 . -->
    <versionNumber>1.0.0</versionNumber>
</application>
```

This is the batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F %%i IN ('XML.EXE sel -t -c -N x="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/17.0" "//x:versionNumber" "myApp-app.xml"') DO SET version=%%i
ECHO Version is %version%
```

(I also tried to use "//x:application/versionNumber" instead of "//x:versionNumber")

The error I receive is:

```
failed to load external entity "x"
Attempt to load network entity http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/17.0
failed to load external entity "/x:application/filename"
Version is NaN
```

I tried changing the order of arguments but this results in either completely broken command or the error message "*Bad namespace option: namespace should have the form <prefix>=<url>*", whereas I always made sure that the namespace definition *x="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/17.0"* is stated behind *-N*.

Can anyone see what may cause the errors and why it is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-N x=http...` options must go first just after the `sel`. Outside of the `FOR` construct, this works

```
XMLSTARLET.EXE sel -N x=http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/17.0 -t -c //x:versionNumber myApp-app.xml
```

but it gives `<versionNumber xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/17.0">1.0.0</versionNumber>`. I think you were after just `1.0.0`, so you should change the `-c` (`--copy-of`) to `-v` (`--value-of`).

```
XMLSTARLET.EXE sel -N x=http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/17.0 -T -t -v //x:versionNumber myApp-app.xml
```

`-T` is short for `--text` (as opposed to the default XML output).

---

Inside the `FOR` construct, the `=` needs to be quoted, the following all work:

```
FOR /F %%i IN ('XMLSTARLET.EXE sel -N "x=http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/17.0" -T -t -v //x:versionNumber myApp-app.xml') DO SET version=%%i
FOR /F %%i IN ('XMLSTARLET.EXE sel -N x"="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/17.0 -T -t -v //x:versionNumber myApp-app.xml') DO SET version=%%i
FOR /F %%i IN ('XMLSTARLET.EXE sel -N x^=http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/17.0  -T -t -v //x:versionNumber myApp-app.xml') DO SET version=%%i
```

Comment: Works like a charm!
Many thanks for the solution and for additional explanations!