# How can I add a new child element to the web element in my bootstrap.xml file using xmlstarlet?

Tags: dockerfile, xmlstarlet

How can I add a new child element `<app url="metrics" war="metrics.war"/>` to the `web` element in the xml file below using xmlstarlet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!--
  ~ Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  ~ contributor license agreements. See the NOTICE file distributed with
  ~ this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  ~ The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  ~ (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  ~ the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
  ~
  ~     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  ~
  ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  ~ distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  ~ WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  ~ See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  ~ limitations under the License.
  -->
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.org/schema">
  <jaas-security domain="activemq"/>
  <!-- artemis.URI.instance is parsed from artemis.instance by the CLI startup.
        This is to avoid situations where you could have spaces or special characters on this URI -->
  <server configuration="file:/var/lib/./artemisBroker/etc//broker.xml"/>
  <!-- The web server is only bound to localhost by default -->
  <web bind="http://0.0.0.0:8161" path="web">
    <app url="activemq-branding" war="activemq-branding.war"/>
    <app url="artemis-plugin" war="artemis-plugin.war"/>
    <app url="console" war="console.war"/>
  </web>
</broker>
```

This is in a `docker` image, I pull `ActiveMQ` and do that setup, then I want to add a [Prometheus Metrics Plugin](https://github.com/jbertram/artemis-prometheus-metrics-plugin). I copy the required `jar`/`war` files to the correct folders, but now I need to modify the `bootstrap.xml` to reference the war file.

I can see in the `Dockerfile` that `xmlstartlet` has been used to modify the `bind` attribute like this:

```
RUN cd /var/lib/artemisBroker/etc && \
  xmlstarlet ed -L -N amq="http://activemq.org/schema" \
    -u "/amq:broker/amq:web/@bind" \
    -v "http://0.0.0.0:8161" bootstrap.xml
```

But I cannot figure out how to add a new element.
I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30348920/xmlstarlet-namespace-issue-cant-extract-node-value-from-xml), which helped clarify some things, but I'm still doing something wrong.
After some trial and error I came up with the following:

```
xmlstarlet ed -L -N amq="http://activemq.org/schema"\
-s "amq:broker/amq:web" \
-t elem -n "app"  bootstrap.xml
```

Which seems to run fine, and adds an `<app />` element, but I can't figure out how to add the attributes I want without overwriting the other `<app />` elements in the file.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
xmlstarlet ed --subnode "//web" --type elem -n app --insert  "// web //app[3]"  --type attr --name "url" --value "metrics" --insert  "// web //app[3]" --type attr --name "war" --value "metrics.war" bootstrap.xml
```

and see if it works.

Comment: That didn't work I'm afraid. You also have `// web` in a couple of places, not sure if the space is supposed to be there or not? tried it both ways, it just outputs the contents of the file, no error message. When I add an element as in my example there is no output.

Comment: @mal - The space between the backslahes and "web" shouldn't be there. More generally, the code in the answer definitely works with the sample xml in the question. Obviously, I have no access to your actual xml so I can't tell why it doesn't work there.

Comment: OK thanks for your help. I'll try debug it and accept your answer.

Comment: @mal Sounds good; also, if the final answer is not something trivial with the code or xml (like a typo, etc.), can you return and post a comment explaining it (just out of curiosity)?